# select a child element in jquery object

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm new to jquery and I have a basic question now.

I have a jquery object got from a jquery selector. e.g

```
var obj = $('#certainTR');
```

Now, I want to get the element in this  object and I cannot use '#certainTR > date' in a selector because '#certain' is not passed in my subroutine. Is there anyway to make a selection base on a object? Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

use [`.children()`](http://api.jquery.com/children/)

```
var obj = $('#certainTR'); // #certainTR
obj.children('.date'); // #certainTR > .date
```

I suggest you should visit [Tree Traversal](http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/tree-traversal/)